# What is the difference between a frustum and a prismoid?

Tags: geometry, terminology

The definitions of mathematical terms frustum and prismoid are hard to describe precisely. What are the subtle differences in meaning between them? An explanation supported by figures would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A frustum is any segment of any solid between two parallel planes; even though common usage refers mostly to frusta of cones and pyramids, there's no requirement that they must be so. Prismoids must be polyhedral (so in particular does not include frusta of cones) with lateral sides trapezoids. While this includes all frusta of pyramids, prismoids also include shapes that cannot be obtained as a frustum of a pyramid.

Comment: In particular: they cannot be "delineated" because they overlap. Neither, however, is a sub-category of the other.